# Why does it not cause a warning that gamm4 uses internal function from mgcv?

Tags: r, mgcv

I am puzzled by a fact that I noticed when reading the source code of the [gamm4](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gamm4) package.

In two places, it imports internal functions from [mgcv](https://cran.r-project.org/package=mgcv).

One place is in the `gamm4.setup` function (link to code [here](https://github.com/cran/gamm4/blob/8c89289807ee7092229b13d7129b3eca33101a89/R/gamm4.r#L21-L23))

```r
  G <- mgcv:::gam.setup(formula,pterms,
                 data=data,knots=knots,sp=NULL,
                 min.sp=NULL,H=NULL,absorb.cons=TRUE,sparse.cons=0,gamm.call=TRUE)
```

Another place is in the gamm4 function (link to code [here](https://github.com/cran/gamm4/blob/8c89289807ee7092229b13d7129b3eca33101a89/R/gamm4.r#L161)):

```r
  var.summary <- mgcv:::variable.summary(gp$pf,dl,nrow(mf)) ## summarize the input data
```

In the DESCRIPTION file, it lists mgcv under Depends (link to full DESCRIPTION file [here](https://github.com/cran/gamm4/blob/master/DESCRIPTION)):

```r
Depends: R (>= 2.9.0), methods, Matrix, lme4 (>= 1.0), mgcv (>= 1.7-23)
```

Furthermore, in NAMESPACE it imports mgcv, although I don't think that's relevant for my question. Link to NAMESPACE [here](https://github.com/cran/gamm4/blob/master/NAMESPACE).

This use of internal functions from another package causes a warning if I do exactly the same thing in a package that I'm developing, leaving the following WARNING from `R CMD check`:

```
❯ checking dependencies in R code ... WARNING
  Unexported objects imported by ':::' calls:
    ‘mgcv:::gam.setup’ ‘mgcv:::variable.summary’
    See the note in ?`:::` about the use of this operator.
    Including base/recommended package(s):
    ‘mgcv’
```

However, gamm4 has no NOTEs or WARNINGs on CRAN, and I can confirm by downloading the source code and running `R CMD check` on it, that everything is fine for gamm4.

Now my question is:

- What is it that I'm missing? What is the trick that the author of gamm4 does, so that using an internal function from another package causes no WARNING?

Note: I'm aware that using an internal still may not be good practice, e.g., as noted in `help(":::")`, so my question mainly regards why `R CMD check` accepts this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** thanks to @GaborCsardi's comment, I learnt that using `:::` in a package doesn't raise a warning if you are also the maintainer of the package from which you use the function.

For example, if you're the maintainer of the package `foo`, you can use `foo:::` in another package `foo2` without having this warning. Note that this should only work if you use the same email address in the `Maintainer` field in `DESCRIPTION`.

In your example, Simon Wood is the maintainer of both `gamm4` and `mgcv`.

Comment: Why don't you change both maintainer emails to yours, then you'll see that `:::` is allowed as long as both any email addresses are the same. There is no whitelist AFAICT.

Comment: Interesting, I had no idea about that. Thanks for the correction, I'll update my answer. Is this mentioned somewhere in the docs?

Comment: @ØysteinS just tagging you so that you see the updated answer, which is drastically different from the previous one

Comment: I haven't seen this documented, but I am not sure. FWIW here it is in the code: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/fed508dfd0bc45887be29c5a11f9b1e5b68c22f9/src/library/tools/R/QC.R#L6226

Comment: That's crazy!  Seems like an odd loophole ...

Comment: I mean, if you are calling _your own_ internal function, then you probably know what you are doing.